# Modify depth buffer in Scene Kit using shaders

Tags: shader, scenekit, metal, depth-buffer

Is it possible to modify the depth buffer for rendering one model by subtracting the inverse of a depth buffer from a different model? e.g. cut a hole in one model from another by saying that depth tests fail in the first model in the area of the second model.

*Edit*
One of the reasons I want to do this is because of Z-fighting between the two models at larger distances. I have tried changing the rendering order of a "cut out" node that is invisible but this causes Z-fighting issues itself at distances.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to achieve this but the simplest one is probably to

1. Have a geometry for the occluder
2. Set the `colorBufferWriteMask` property of the occluder's material to `SCNColorMaskNone` (it will still write to the depth buffer which is an independent property, namely `writesToDepthBuffer`)
3. Eventually set the node's `renderingOrder` to `-1` (or any value that will make it always render before the occluded node) if there are issues with culling or sorting

Comment: Thanks! I have actually tried a similar technique but my problem is with Z-fighting at large distances. This solution is great for cutting holes but it doesn't help in my specific case. I have updated my question with these details. Are there other techniques you could recommend?

Comment: Coming in late, but a couple of ideas for fighting z-fighting:
1) Make sure your camera near & far planes are set reasonably. Sometimes you can just move the near plane a few orders of magnitude (e.g. from 0.001 --> 0.1), which will give enough floating point precision to ~fix the issue. Many variables though.
2) Modify the model, either by changing the source 3D asset or by pushing all vertices out a little bit at runtime using a geometry shader/shaderModifier.